# How to get a SSH terminal in browser using AngularJS?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, ssh

This is a project for my CV and I am trying to get a terminal in AngularJS using Spring as back-end. I did most of the back-end, database connections, SSH connections, etc, but I don't have any idea on how to get the terminal from back-end to front-end. Can someone help me? Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Your question is too broad, try to specify it so that people can answer it instead of just giving technology/approach suggestions which can't be objectively marked as the correct answer.

Comment: But that is what I need, some suggestions/approaches to try them.